# Error on @Autowired in custom UserDetails class

Tags: spring, spring-security, mybatis

```
data source configuration 


@Configuration
@MapperScan("com.su.api.db.mapper")
public class DataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class);
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/esstat?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }


   @Bean
   public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager()
   {
       return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
   }

   @Bean
   public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean() throws Exception{
       System.out.println("set sqlSessionFactory");
       SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
       sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());

       sessionFactory.setMapperLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:/mapper/*.xml"));


       return sessionFactory;
   }


}
```

user interface that is in @mapperScan path

```
public interface User {

    public String  FIELD_USER_NUM = "user_num";
    public String FIELD_ID = "id";
    public String FIELD_PASSWORD = "password";
    public String FIELD_LAST_LOGIN = "last_login";
    public String FIELD_LAST_LOGIN_ip = "last_login_ip";
    public String FIELD_CREATED_DATE = "created_date";


    public int getCount();
    public Map getUser(String id);
}
```

custom userDetailsService

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Autowired
    User user;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LoginUser loginUser =  new LoginUser(username, username, false, false, false, false, null);
        return loginUser;
    }
```

In custom UserDetailsService class, I tries to retrieve user information from database by user

```
@Autowired User user
```

However, an error occurs..

```
    ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springDataUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'user'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.heesu.api.db.mapper.User' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1377)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:865)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5641)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.heesu.api.db.mapper.User' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:595)
    ... 24 more
May 25, 2019 5:09:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
심각: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springDataUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'user'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.heesu.api.db.mapper.User' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1377)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:865)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5641)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.heesu.api.db.mapper.User' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:595)
    ... 24 more
```

I tested @Autowired User user in a Controller class, and I found everything works fine.

The error occurs when tomcat is starting up.
So, I can't retrieve user information from database. How can I fix this problem??

Answer (score 1):

As per the code provided User is an interface here and not a class. When we mark any reference with an @Autowired annotation then spring expects that to be either a spring bean class or there should be at least one implementing spring bean class for the same and that class need to be marked with a stereotype annotation i.e., @Component or configure as @Bean in your spring configuration class.
For example,

```
@Component
class User {

//Attributes
}
```

or if you wish to make it Spring bean using @Bean annotation the you can do so as you have done for others in your Configuration class like below

```
class SpringBeanConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public User user() {
     return new User();
   }
}
```